# RedirectToRoute throws Exception: No route matches the supplied values, when I pass url as query-parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

**RedirectToRoute throws InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values**, when I pass route-value from query-parameter (which is a route-template-string) but works fine when query-parameter is null.

I'm trying to redirect to returnUrl using `RedirectToRoute(routeName, routeValues)` after login but any attempt to do so throws InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values, **but works when returnUrl is null or empty.**

Here I'm converting route-template to route-name using `FormatRoute(route-template`

```
[Route("/"), HttpGet("account-login/{returnUrl:alpha?}", Name = "account_login"), AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromQuery] string returnUrl = null)
        {
            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

            return View(new LoginViewModel { ReturnUrl = returnUrl?.FormatRoute() });
        }
```

Here I login and try to navigate to *verify_login_token* but it fails when returnUrl has a value but works when it is null or empty.

```
[AllowAnonymous, HttpPost("account-login/{returnUrl:alpha?}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ResponseHelper response = await context.LoginAsync(mapper.Map<LoginDTO>(model));

                switch(response.Status)
                {
                    case ResultCode.Success:
                        return this.RedirectToLocal(returnUrl ?? "/home_page");
                    case ResultCode.RequiresTwoFactor:
                        return this.RedirectToLocal("/verify_login_token", new { tokenProvider = ConstantHelper.TokenProvider, rememberMe = model.RememberMe, returnUrl }, ResponseHelper.ResponseHandler(response));
                    case ResultCode.UnconfirmedEmail:
                        AuthenticationDTO authentication = response.Data;

                        response = await context.GetUserClaimsAsync(model.EmailAddress);

                        if (response.Status.Equals(ResultCode.Success) && response.Data != null)
                        {
                            string callbackUrl = HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = authentication.UserId, token = authentication.Token }, Request.Scheme));

                            string recipientName = response.GetData<IList<Claim>>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Type.Equals("UserName")).Value;

                            response = await context.CreateConfirmationEmailAsync(model.EmailAddress, recipientName, callbackUrl);
                        }
                        break;
                    case ResultCode.Error:
                    case ResultCode.Exception:
                        return this.RedirectToLocal("/account_login", null, ResponseHelper.ResponseHandler(response));
                }
            }
```

I'm trying to navigate to this action method

```
[AllowAnonymous, HttpGet("verify-login-token/{tokenProvider:alpha}/{rememberMe:bool}/{returnUrl:alpha?}", Name = "verify_login_token")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> VerifyLoginToken(string tokenProvider, bool rememberMe, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            // Require that the user has already logged in via username/password or external login
            ResponseHelper response = await context.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();

            if (!response.Status.Equals(ResultCode.Success))
            {
                this.SetViewErrorMessage(response);

                return View("Error");
            }

            return View(new VerifyLoginTokenVM { TokenProvider = tokenProvider, RememberMe = rememberMe, ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        }
```

I have a helper function to help me validate routes

```
public static IActionResult RedirectToLocal(this Controller context, string routeName, object routeValues = null, ResponseFormat response = null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(routeName))
            {
                if (context.Url.IsLocalUrl(routeName))
                {
                    routeName = routeName.Contains("/", System.StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? routeName.TrimStart('/') : routeName;

                    if (response != null)
                    {
                        return context.RedirectToRoute(routeName, routeValues).WithResponseData(response);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return context.RedirectToRoute(routeName, routeValues);
                    }
                }
            }

            return context.RedirectToRoute("home_page");
        }
```

Any attempt to redirect to the url in returnUrl fails: for example the following : `this.RedirectToLocal(returnUrl ?? "/home_page");` does not work. I have added a helper function to convert any route-template to route-name using code below:

```
public static string FormatRoute(this string routeTemplate)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(routeTemplate))
            {
                return "/home_page";
            }

            return routeTemplate.Replace("-", "_");
        }
```

If returnUrl has */create-user-profile*, then `FormatRoute("/create-user-profile")` returns */create_user_profile*

Currently I'm getting *InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values*, when I try to redirect to returnUrl. I'm looking for help in understanding what I did wrong and how to correct that mistake.

Answer (score 2):

[RedirectToRoute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoroute?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_RedirectToRoute_System_String_System_Object_) uses a [route name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0#route-name), while you seem to pass an `url` instead.

A [Redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirect?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_Redirect_System_String_), which redirects to an `url`, might be sufficient for your use case.

Edit: To include the `routeValues` in the url, with a little rewrite you could use [QueryString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.querystring?view=aspnetcore-3.0), e.g.:

```
var uri = "/verify_login_token" + QueryString.Create(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("userId", "yourUserId"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("token", "yourToken"),
}).ToUriComponent();
```

Comment: thank you for your insightful pointer, but `Redirect` has no overload that takes route-values.

Comment: You are welcome, I added an example for including route values.

Comment: thank you for your kind and elaborate response, I will gladly try it out and revert to you with an update.